# Grunt debugging from Webstorm

Tags: node.js, debugging, intellij-idea, gruntjs, webstorm

Its possible to run grunt tasks within WebStorm through external tools.  However, is it possible to avail debugging with external tools? By running tasks like `grunt server` or `grunt test` within WebStorm, it would make debugging a lot easier if it's possible with external tools like grunt.

Comment: Check this small article -- use any online translator if required: http://habrahabr.ru/post/170441/

Comment: The mentioned article refers to this WebStorm help file: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/running-and-debugging-node-js.html.

Answer (score 98):

You have to run **grunt-cli** as a Node application:

- Create a new Node.js Run/Debug configuration: **Run->Edit configurations...**
- In **Path to Node** choose your node binary, ie: `/Users/someuser/nvm/v0.10.5/bin/node`
- In **Working Directory**, choose your `Gruntfile.js` directory, ie `/Projects/someproject`
- In **Path to Node App JS File**, choose your Grunt CLI path (you can choose the `grunt-cli` symlink created on your node bin directory, WebStorm will use the symlink target), ie: `/Users/someuser/nvm/v0.10.5/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt`
  (`C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt` on Windows 7)
- In **Application parameters** enter the Grunt task to run, eg `default` or `test`

Click on Run or Debug and you are done :)

Comment: Is there a way to config webstorm to run Grunt Test automatically when file is saved? Thanks

Comment: I never did it before, but probably if you go to Project Settings and configure a custom file watch (look for "File Watchers" then click on the plus button at the bottom and choose custom), you can launch node with Grunt each time that a file changes. (I usually use grunt watch in a second terminal instead of using File Watchers)

Comment: Any ideas why starting a debug session for this takes a lot of time to start up?

Comment: I think that ItelliJ guys are the best to answer that question (you can create a ticket here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/).
But my bet is that when NodeJS starts in debug mode, probably some V8 optimizations are off, so maybe loading all the dependencies of Grunt with debug support takes more time. Another possible cause could be some network config in your machine (NodeJS debugger uses TCP to expose the debug interface, that's used by WS). But again... my "answers" are just guesses :)

Comment: I get it works, when I set the "Path to Node App JS file" as path to grunt binary file: "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt"

Comment: For me, I used the output of `which grunt` to find the correct **Path to Node App JS File**

Comment: Starting Webstorm from the terminal also helps its environment variables available to Webstorm.

Comment: starting from WEbStrom10 it became even more convenient: now you could select grunt on step **Run->Edit configurations...**

Answer (score 9):

I just happened to try this in WebStorm 10 today.  I'm not sure if it's a new feature but WebStorm have integrated the steps described by @diego so you don't have to perform them manually:

1. Click View > Tool Windows > Grunt to display the Grunt window in WebStorm.
2. Right-click on any task and choose "Debug"

You can set breakpoints etc. in `Gruntfile.js` just like you would any other file.

Comment: You have to make sure you include any env vars that you have in the run configs because you lose these when going via the Tool Windows via the `Edit 'task' settings...` option when right-clicking