# How can I run Grunt as a external tool from IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, gruntjs

I've tried to run Grunt.js before I compile and launch my project without any luck.

I've tried to run it with the "Run External Tool" option in IntelliJ configuration edition menu, it asks you for the path of the program you want to run, I've tried to add the Grunt path in /usr/bin but it tells me that the node environment cannot be found.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Installed Node.js via Homebrew on OSX, grunt via npm. After fiddling around, it now works with following in IntelliJ Ultimate 12:

Edit Configurations -> Add new configuration -> Node.js

In the Run/Debug Configurations window:

- Path to Node: **/usr/local/bin/node**
- Node Parameters: ***empty***
- Working Directory: **_directory_of_gruntfile_**
- Path to Node App JS File: **/usr/local/bin/grunt**

Comment: I believe you have a typo in your "Path to Node"

Comment: Note that in IntelliJ 13 the "Path to Node App JS File" setting is called "JavaScript file", and it doesn't support path to symlinks it has to point to the actual file.

Comment: Just to add to the accepted answer with a tip from below is that this only works after you've installed the NodeJS plugin. It's an official JetBrains plugin, but is not bundled with IntelliJ by default.

Comment: What if your development environment and execution/run environment are on diff. OS, but on same machine. For example I have a VM with ubuntu server on my windows machine, where I'm executing `grunt serve`, but code development is happening on Windows. Is there anyway to refer to a grunt, that is on VM on ubuntu server?

Answer (score 9):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17452803/61624) helped me more than what you selected as the correct answer.  The difference is that this one is for webstorm.  Here's what I'd do: I'd [install the node.js plugin in intellij](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/running-and-debugging-node-js.html), then configure it like this:

- Path to Node: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe`
- Working Directory: directory with your Gruntfile.js in it
- Path to Node App JS File: `C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt`
- Application Parameters: Whatever you want to pass to grunt as parameters

This is on windows 7.

Comment: This worked for me in IDEA 13 with the note about '"Path to Node App JS File" setting is called "JavaScript file"' from the comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: Still up to date with IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: After above configuration, you can right click on Gruntfile.js and select 'Show Grunt Tasks' to see and run tasks in intelliJ.

Answer (score 5):

Configuration that works for me (I'm on Windows 7):

Program: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe

Parameters: ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt

Working directory:$ProjectFileDir$

Comment: I managed to make it work on OS X based in your configuration using the following conf:  
   
Program: /usr/local/bin/node   
 
Parameters : /usr/local/bin/Grunt  
 
Working Directory : $ModuleFileDir$

Comment: For OSX I had to have the parameters as: /usr/local/share/npm/bin/grunt, however when I run this I get Unable to find local grunt. Any ideas?

Comment: I had to use C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt because it did not work in my intelliJ, it is v13.0.1

Answer (score 1):

On Mac GUI applications get their environment variables from /etc/launchd.conf. Because of this the "terminal" in IntelliJ doesn't know about Node or Grunt because it doesn't know where to look for them. If you add your PATH environment variable to /etc/launchd.conf and restart your computer IntelliJ will be able to run Grunt as part of the server deployment.

The easiest way to get this in there is to do:

```
echo $PATH | pbcopy
```

and then in /etc/launchd.conf put in:

```
setenv PATH pasteResultsFromTheClipboardHere
```

Note: you have to edit launchd.conf as sudo or it won't let you write the file. Your path variable should contain the locations where node and grunt are installed.