# stepping through the code exits debugging - why?

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm

I've configured webstorm debugging options to debug grunt according to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043484/grunt-debugging-from-webstorm). Then I put debugger into my file and clicked 'Debug'. The process started and the execution stopped at the debugger. So far so good. Yet, when I press F8 or click 'Step over' the execution continues not in debug mode and I get the following output 'process disconnected unexpectedly'. What could be the reasons for that? What's interesting is that when I click on 'run to cursor' or 'resume program' it stops on cursor or next breakpoint.

Comment: "step over" generally refers to running the current function in one go, whereas "step in" runs the code line by line, stepping into every function. I'm assuming all of your breakpoints are in this one function and are being stepped over. I'm not familiar with webstorm but try finding the shortcut for "step in", often F9 or F11

Comment: Just found the docs, use F7 instead of F8 ([source](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/debug-tool-window.html))

Comment: Very helpful... Could you add your code section which you are debugging or elaborate on what still isn't working?

Comment: I know the difference between `step in` and `step over`. Neither work in my case. And if there is no function call these methods will work the same. Thanks for your efforts anyway.

Comment: Cheers, if you're still looking for help try giving some more details.